# UICollectionView itemsize vs. size in elementsForRect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

If I have set an item size in my collectionviewflowlayout I can't change the size in my collectionviewflowlayout subclass's layoutAttributesForElementsInRect. If I do, the cell is resized (gets smaller) but does so within the area defined by the itemSize property. In other words, I have space on the top and bottom of my cell (I have a vertically scrolling cv).

Furthermore, I have sizeForItemAtIndexPath. It seems all of these methods and properties are doing the same thing. Where do I do my work?

Comment: Do you really need to subclass it? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well this question goes hand in hand with another post i just made. Could you take a look at that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955578/setting-uicollectionviewcell-size-when-cell-is-using-autolayout I also have some other requirements re: decoration views which is why i have to subclass.

Comment: The method sizeForItemAtIndexPath is supposed to be implemented in your collection view delegate and allows you to set the size of each element individually. Anyway the row's height would be calculated as a maximum of the row's cells' heights - this is the way the flow layout works.

Comment: I know that. But also a cell's layout attributes can be changed within the attributesForElementsInRect. You can set a size, center, alpha, etc. here that gets applied to the cell.